# PHP - Submit button does not work

Tags: php

I just started to learn PHP. I use a "Missing Manual" series book. I downloaded PHP 5, I installed it with the option "Do not setup a web server". From command line I can launch a php test program. But I can launch from browser.

The HTML code :

```
 <html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <form action="scripts/sayHelloWeb.php" method="POST">
           <p><i>Enter your name:</i> 
           <input type="text" name="name" size="20" /></p>
           <p><input type="submit" value="Say Hello" /></p>
        </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

and sayHelloWeb.php code is :

```
<html> 
<head></head> 

  <body> 
    <h1>Hello, <?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?></h1> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Well, the HTML works : the text input and the buttons are displayed
, but php does not display any name. That is the "name" variable is empty. It displays only : "Hello, ". The folder scripts exists, the path is correct.

Where I did wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: try to check that it is set or not  <h1>Hello, `<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : "not set"; ?></h1> `

Comment: you need a web server in order to run PHP files

Comment: @E B : do you have web server or you trying it like html?

Comment: Even though the browser opens your PHP files and outputs the HTML in them, it does not mean the actual PHP code is run. You need Apache or IIS or some other web server to run it.

Comment: you need to ensure that your server knows where the php modules are stored and need to invoke them accordingly.

btw which platform are you working on? do you have installed apache with php?

Okay Get easy installation of php with apache and MySQL on any platform use [XAMPP](http://downloadxampp.com/)

Comment: Tested and works, like @cornelb said: you must have a web server

Answer (score 3):

You have to setup a web server otherwise you can't run php file. if you check the source of `sayHelloWeb.php` after loading it, you will see that the php code is commented which means that it's not runned.

Make sure to install a web server. [Wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/) is a good choise for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a **Hypertext Preprocessor** meaning that its not meant to be be interpreted on the client but rather on the server end, prior to the delivery of the HTML document itself. Installing a PHP interpreter along with a **capable web server** is required to make PHP work.

If you are seeing PHP code in your browser you can be sure that PHP is not set up correctly with your web server. Installing PHP itself merely installs a local PHP interpreter without setting it up to handle incoming web requests, for that you need a "proper" web server like Apache or IIS.

A good way to test if PHP is working is by creating this document:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

and loading it into your browser. Upon successful installation of PHP, a detailed (extremely verbose) status of PHP and web server components can be seen.

Answer (score -1):

First check if is submit btn clicket. Than get value from field. Whitout that u will get notice

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $msg = $_POST['name'];

}
?>
<html> 
<head></head> 

  <body> 
    <h1>Hello, <?php echo $msg ?></h1> 
    </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Try to use  isset() and empty() on $_REQUEST

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['param']))
{
   if(empty($_REQUEST['param']))
   {
      ///
   }
}
```

or

```
if ((isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) && (!empty($_REQUEST['name'])))
{
    $name= $_REQUEST['name'];
}
```

Comment: Again, `$_POST` is a subset of `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv why are you dv everyone using $_POST ?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why his code won't work, except the fact that he's not running it at all. He is opening the .php files in a browser, and, like any other text file, nothing in it is _executed_, it is just treated as invalid HTML.

Comment: @RonniSkansing $_REQUEST is not the issue. It's the web server not being installed

Comment: Try to put in that doc ``phpinfo();`` and what u see?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv you are right that the answers are low quality. The code works fine, it just needs a webserver. But recommending everyone to use $_REQUEST is IMO a bad thing to do, placing a dv and a comment about using REQUEST instead of the specific request type seems like dv for using $_POST. But it makes sense that answer is not $_POST when $_REQUEST is not the problem

Comment: Then post a comment on the question post advising him against it. That's how everyone does this.

Comment: @rullof (and to all :-)). I have installed Apache. I entered http://localhost in address box. It said that Apache works. Then I run the HTML file. Same thing: i.e. displays only "Hello" without name. I underlined that when I installed PHP, I did it with the option "Do not setup a webserver". Andthe resultis the one I wrote about. Then, I re-installed it with the option "Apache Server" and the result is the same.

Comment: @EB I highly recommending you to install http://www.wampserver.com it's the best choice for you as a beginner!

Comment: I deleted Apache and php. I reinstalled Apache adn PHP. I changed the listen port from 80 to 122. I checked to see if it works on localhost:122. The file index.html from htdocs is loaded and displays: "It works". I tried to open a file info.php:

Comment: The file is : <?php
phpinfo();
?> but it works only in command line and not in browser. I think the server is installed. But for whatever reason it does not work. My OS is Windows 7. Thanks foe any other ides.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
  <body> 
    <h1>Hello, <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></h1> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Should work?

Comment: Wait, you tried doing php without a server - that was the issue?

Comment: First time, yes. I followed the guidelines in the books I mentioned earlier. Second time, I deleted Apache, I deleted PHP and after I re-installed Apache and PHP. I reinstalled PHP with the option"Apache". And it was the same result.

Answer (score -2):

These fields are stored in `$_POST` array.
Try this: `echo $_POST['name'];`

Comment: It's wrong, the variables are in `$_REQUEST` as well: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is `$_GET` and `$_POST` combined by default as of PHP 5.3. Earlier it contained $_COOKIES and other stuff also.

Comment: No it should not. It's exactly the same.